# Authenticate a Google PubSub POST request using OAuth2

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to form a POST to publish a Google PubSub message. I can't use the client libraries because they use gRPC which is incompatible with Google App Engine. I can form the critical POST request, but I'm not sure how to authenticate it using OAuth2.

This link shows what I'm doing, but it obscures the authentication part.
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish

(If GAE standard environment would support gRPC this would not matter.)

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray attr = new JSONArray();
obj.put("script_name","foo_script.py");
obj.put("script_args","arg1");
attr.put(obj);
JSONObject jsontop = new JSONObject();
jsontop.put("messages",attr);
URL url = new URL("https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{my-URL}/topics/topic_run_script:publish");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

This code comes back "401 : UNAUTHENTICATED". How do I authenticate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine has an API to fetch an access token that you can use to when calling Google services. For documentation and an example, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_google_apis

You might also be able to use the pubsub client library on GAE Std if you switch to the Java 8 environment. [This doc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java#supported-platforms) implies that it should work.

Comment: Thanks @David for the useful link. The lines I was missing were:    final AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
    final AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken = appIdentity.getAccessToken(scopes);
    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.getAccessToken());